# How to pass JSON data to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a JSON in a variable. The fetch() prints out the JSON correctly in the console, but the for loop shows that the variable is empty (undefined). What am I doing wrong?

```
var mydates;    
fetch("{% static 'dates.json' %}")
.then(function(u){return u.json();})
.then(function(json){mydates = json;})
.then(function(){console.log(mydates);})    //The json is printed in the console just fine

for (let year in mydates){                  // This should print in the console 2018, 2019, 2020
    console.log(year)                       // but instead mydates is marked as undefined
};
```

My **dates.json** file looks like this:

```
{
   "2018": {
       "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
       "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
       "March": ["week8","week9","week10","week11"]
   },
   "2019": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8","week9","week10","week11"]
    },
    "2020": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8","week9","week10","week11"]
    }
}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: `fetch()` is **asynchronous**. You are trying to eat a pizza before it gets delivered

Comment: Thanks but after reading the original answer, I'm still completely lost. So what should be the right code ? Thanks

Comment: Consume the data in the last `then()` when it actually exists

Comment: ok, great hint thanks. Any chance you could show me what the last .then() should look like for me to finally understand ?

Comment: `.then(function(json){mydates = json; console.log(mydates)})`

Comment: Thanks, but in the for loop, mydates remains undefined... it's driving me nuts ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226786/discussion-between-joss-and-charlietfl).